# Printar Vetor em C

Tags: c, matriz

Gostaria de printar um vetor[300] e outro [500], mas de certa forma que aparentar-se ser, para o usuario, uma matriz... por exemplo, fiz um de [100], onde fiz o loop para printar este vetor e um "if" para ele quebrar a linha de forma que quando chegasse em valores divisiveis por 10 o realizasse como dito.

```
for(l=0;l<100;l++){
if(l%10==0) // if de quebra de linha 
printf("\n");
if(vetorCEM[l]==0)
printf("[%2d]-",l+1);
```

o segundo if é apenas para mostrar o conteudo explicito do meu vetor, mas o que quero destacar mesmo é este exemplo que usei, mas para os de 300 e 500 não obtive sucesso, gostaria que alguem pudesse me ajudar, plisss!!

Answer (score 1):

seu código funcionou com 100 porque 100 é um quadrado perfeito (um numero que tem uma raiz inteira), ou seja, a matriz ficou 10x10, agora 300 e 500 não são... Se seu objetivo é conseguir uma matriz com o numero de linhas e colunas igual, nesses valores será impossível, agora se isso não for necessário, você pode usar qualquer relação, até mesmo a do i%10 para conseguir um resultado ou alguma outra que aproxime mais o numero de linhas com o de colunas ex: para 300, i%30 que vai ficar 30x10 e assim por diante.

Comment: sim sim, fiz o de 100 nessa teoria de 10x10, e imaginei o de 300, que em uma matriz seria 15x20, e o de 500 20x25... para o de 300 coloquei %15==0, ele até funcionou porém até uma certa quantidade do vetor, da mesma forma aconteceu no de 500, que usei %20==0... a intenção não era realmente printar uma "matriz perfeita", mas sim quebrar as linhas nesses parametros de acordo com até onde o looping vá

Comment: @ViniSRB Mas 15x20 não forma um quadrado, e o mesmo para 20x25. Querer que uma matriz de 300 elementos seja mostrada como um quadrado perfeito não é possivel como explicado nesta resposta, pois 10x10 dá 100 mas não há nenhum numero inteiro que multiplicado por ele proprio dê 300. Agora se o que pretende é uma aproximação então convem tornar isso também claro na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Lembre-se que as posições do vetor começam em 0 e terminam em x - 1, onde o x é o tamanho do vetor. Então o if de quebra de linha deveria ficar assim: `if((i + 1) % y == 0)`,
onde:

i: contador;

y: posição da quebra de linha.

Answer (score -2):

Creio que não seja possível, pois um elemento de uma matriz é a intercessão de 2 vetores.
Crie uma matriz `m[300][500]` e utilize 2 `for`:

```
for(int i = 0; i<300; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j <500; j++)
    {
        Printf("%d ",m[i][j]);
    }
}
```